# Scientific speculation in geography related questions

Tags: discussion, scope

During my stay at HSE I have come across several posts that overlay geography layout mentioned in texts to present geography of Indian subcontinent. It is not just limited to mountains and rivers but extends to locations where events transpired. My question is whether that is bringing scientific speculation.

For instance Himalayas kickstarted 50 million yrs ago as per science (when the plate collided with Asia landmass yada yada). And let's say we have mention of Himalayas for an event that took place in 4th Mahayuga in scripture. Then can it not be possible that Himalayas in scriptures are different than the ones we refer today.

Kindly note that in no way I am trying to imply that scriptures are wrong. It can very well be the case that scientific community revises Himalayas age to 200 million yrs. All I am trying to achieve is consistency. If 4 tusk elephant in Ramayana question is closed as scientific speculation then should we not also treat geography related questions as scientific speculation.

Comment: consistency is not as important as correctness.